# jQuery .submit method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am using Jconfirm together with jQuery to make a confirmation box.
The problem is that the `.submit` does not work

#### Javascript

```
$('#delete').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
jConfirm("Are you sure you want to delete this link?", "Confirmation", function(r) {  
if (r) { $('#delete').submit(); }
});
```

The  `$('#delete').submit();` seems to be dead.

#### HTML

```
<form action="bla.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="delete">
 <table>
<tr>
<td><label for="category">Category:</label></td><td><select name="category_id"           id="categories">
<option value="1">test</option>
<option value="#" selected="selected">Please select</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="links">Link:</label></td><td width="400"><select name="link_id" id="links">
<option value="#" selected="selected">Please select</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Delete" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: And by "not work" you mean what exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to change

```
if (r) { $('#delete').submit(); }
```

with

```
if (r) { $('#delete').get(0).submit(); }
```

so you call the `submit()` method available for the DOM element

Comment: because you triggered the `submit` method applied to the jQuery selector, but you're calling it recursively so you can submit the form through the method `submit` available natively on form elements.